# How verb can be used after the preposition?

Tags: prepositions, passive-voice, gerunds

Could someone please explain this sentence to me

> I am sick of **being called "Excuse Me**"

[image]
This line was said in the 8th episode of friends.

I recon this is a passive voice.  And "being" is a helping verb(ing form) and "called" is main verb(third form). It is just like

> I am being called "Excuse me".

But the problem is that we are using a proposition(of) in the first sentence. And propositions are being followed by noun,pronoun or gerund.
for example

> Sorry for being late.

I think "being" is gerund here. But in the first sentence "being" doesn't seem a gerund.

So can someone please explain the structure of first sentence and how we can use verb after a preposition.

Comment: "Being called excuse me" is a gerund-participial clause which functions perfectly well as complement of the preposition "be".

Comment: Why do you think it's not a gerund?  I am sick of *waiting*, I am sick of *swimming*, I am sick of *being* _____ - they're all gerunds.

Comment: It's not a gerund; "being" is a verb functioning as head of the passive clause "Being called 'Excuse Me'".

Comment: **Being** is definitely a verb and not a gerund here.The preposition goes with the verb **sick**. I am sick of people calling me "Excuse me". In fact this means that instead of hearing her own name she hears "Excuse me" all the time and this iritates her much.

Comment: @Cardinal I just said that - see my last message.

Comment: @Bill You are right. I will delete mine. I didn't notice your second comment.

Comment: It certainly is a gerund. It is a verbal noun - a form of the verb which functions as the head of a noun phrase. That is exactly what a gerund is in English.

Comment: It might be a gerund phrase of the whole verbial clause "*to be called excuse me*", but that form isn't different from the participle clause from "*I am being called*" staying a participle clause in an [adverbial complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_complement) "*of (me) being called*". [Wikipedia on the matter:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_and_postposition#Different_forms_of_complement) "*Let's think about solving this problem (**complement is a gerund phrase**)*", but also "*In other cases the complement may have the form of an **adjective** or adjective phrase*"

Comment: @BillJ Now i am more confused. first two comment says that it is a gerund. then next comments says it is a verb.I think i should not think too much about the grammatical aspects. Even experts like you are not sure about it ?

Comment: After thinking more about it . I conclude this sentence is equivalent to "I am sick of late working " So working is definitely a gerund here. and late is adjective. So in the same way "being" is a gerund and called is an adjective(a past participial of "call" working as an adjective). Infect "being called"  is itself a past participle phrase(work as adjective) for ex. "being called fat, Joe is really angry" so "being called fat" describes joe. ..I know that is not  100% correct. But i can digest it . because this condition only arrive when we use "being" after a preposition. thanks everyone.

Comment: @beginner My advice to you is to forget the word gerund; it has no place in modern grammar. The traditional gerund is a verb form functioning as or like a noun. Nowadays we look to see whether the word is functioning as a verb or a noun --- that is what's important. In _I'm sick of being called Excuse Me'_  and your two examples, "being" is a **verb** as head of clause.

Comment: @BillJ Yeah you are right. But then i have to leave the rule that preposition must be followed only by the noun,pronoun or gerund. So i would take them as a gerund. i definitely know the meaning. But grammatically  a verb needs subject, And change its form with the tense but gerund don't contain those property. So grammatically they are gerund. but one can call it anything for their understanding. And  understanding is what really matters

Comment: @beginner there is **no** such rule. Prepositions can be followed by subordinate clauses, finite (_I left because I was tired_) or non-finite (_Ed insists on checking everything_). Non-finite clauses usually have no overt subject; in that last example, the clause _checking everything_ has no subject, but it is recoverable from the main clause as being "Ed".

Answer (score 1):

I'm happy with the parsing "being called 'excuse me'" as a nominal clause headed by a gerund "being". This phrase is a non-finite dependent clause. The verb complement form "call (someone) X" which in a passive form becomes "be called X" and as a gerund, "being called X"

The sentence "I am being called X" is present continuous, and here you can see how the gerund form came to be used to form the present continuous tense. So although it has a similar form, it is not really the same as the first sentence. Here "being" is an active particple rather than a gerund.

So there is no problem with "I'm sick of being called 'excuse me'". The preposition "of" precedes the noun phrase "being called..." just as expected. You can form lots of sentences this way:

I'm sick of hotdogs.

I'm sick of the Tories.

I'm sick of working.

I'm sick of the dogs barking.

Answer (score 0):

The woman is fed up with waitressing. Among other things, she doesn't make enough money from the "lousy tips" (i.e., gratuities), and it's too impersonal — nobody addresses her except to say "excuse me" (i.e., not calling her by her name).